# How to create a new object from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have the following dynamic array of objects:

```
[

{
id: "1"
name: "Jane"
age: 25
},

{
id: "2"
name: "John"
age: 35
},

{
id: "3"
name: "James"
age: 27
},
]
```

I need to create new object like this:

```
"peopleSelected:{

"1":
{
"name": "Jane",
"age": 25
},

"2":
{
"name": "John",
"age": 35
},

"3":
{
"name": "James",
"age": 27
},
```

where structure is

```
"id" :
{
"name":name,
"age":"age
}
```

and I need to save this newly created object using useState, I can't figure out how to do that. Please help.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt to do this on your own.

Comment: I'm not in charge of anything here on SO, and I'm sorry you feel the way you do. I only asked you show your attempt which is pretty standard. Asking for help with something that isn't working isn't the same as asking for someone to do it for you which is what you ask. It's ok if you don't know or can't figure something out, when you struggle and overcome that is when you learn, and we're all mostly here to help others. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Jane",
      age: 25,
    },

    {
      id: "2",
      name: "John",
      age: 35,
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "James",
      age: 27,
    },
  ],
  solution = {
    peopleSelected: arr.reduce((acc, { id, name, age }) => {
      acc[id] = { name, age };
      return acc;
    }, {}),
  };

console.log(solution);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use object destructuring as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

let people = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Jane",
        age: 25
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "John",
        age: 35
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "James",
        age: 27
    }
];

function App() {
    const [ selectedPeople, setSelectedPeople ] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(Object.entries(people));
        let extractedArray = Object.entries(people);
        let result = extractedArray.map((item) => {
          return `${item[1].id}: ${{
            "name": item[1].name,
            "age": item[1].age
          }}`
        })
        console.log(result);
        
        // Performing object destructuring and setting the state of selectedPeople as an object
        setSelectedPeople({...people})
    }, [])

    return <div>
        <pre>
            {JSON.stringify(selectedPeople, null, '\t')}
        </pre>
    </div>;
}

export default App;
```